# Learn SQL the Hard Way - Exercise 3 - Inserting Data - cannot find file

Tags: sql, sqlite, echo

[Here is a SQL class I'm taking online.](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex3.html) I think I'm confused more on the setup of the SQL files rather than the SQL itself. The INSERT statements are straightforward.

```
INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name, age)
    VALUES (0, "Zed", "Shaw", 37);

INSERT INTO pet (id, name, breed, age, dead)
    VALUES (0, "Fluffy", "Unicorn", 1000, 0);

INSERT INTO pet VALUES (1, "Gigantor", "Robot", 1, 1);
```

In my Windows command prompt, this runs fine.

```
C:\SQLite> sqlite3 ex3.db < ex2.sql
```

In my ex2.sql, he seems to suggest combining CREATE statements from Lesson 2, with the INSERT statements to create a new ex3.db. It seems to work - no errors.

Then he says to run the following statement to display my INSERT statements.

```
C:\SQLite> sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex3.sql
```

Instead of displaying the INSERT statements, I get the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there an error in the lesson? I don't think he ever asked the user to create an ex3.sql file?

So assuming this was a typo, I changed the echo statement to use ex2.sql, since this is the file that contains my INSERT statements.

I get the following errors when I use sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex2.sql

```
Error: near line 1: table person already exists
Error: near line 8: table pet already exists
Error: near line 16: table person_pet already exists
INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name, age)
        VALUES (0, "Zed", "Shaw", 37);
Error: near line 21: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
INSERT INTO pet (id, name, breed, age, dead)
    VALUES (0, "Fluffy", "Unicorn", 1000, 0);
Error: near line 24: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
INSERT INTO pet VALUES (1, "Gigantor", "Robot", 1, 1);
Error: near line 27: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

Is there a typo in the lesson? Was I supposed to create an ex3.sql file with ONLY the INSERT statements by themselves?

Comment: The commands seem to be working as I'd expect, and the error messages are what I'd expect to see. I don't think debugging someone's online tutorial is within the scope of SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about possible error in an online tutorial

Comment: @MikeW - Which `SE` branch such question would be appropriate for?

Comment: delete ex3.db and perform all commands before `sqlite3 ex3.db < ex2.sql`. now run `sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex2.sql`. You just tried to execute same SQL on existing DB.

Comment: Thanks Nazar, I think I was supposed to run sqlite3 ex3.db < ex2.sql with only the CREATE statements to create the new db. Then create a new sql file called ex3.sql with only the INSERT statements. Then run sqlite3 -echo ex3.db < ex3.sql as per the instructions.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't think there is a branch of SE where this would fit - any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message was trying to tell you that `ex3.sql` could not be found.

You are supposed to use the old `ex2.sql` file to create the tables, and to put the new `INSERT` statements into `ex3.sql`.